# Не работает header()

Tags: php, http

Ребят. Впервые сталкиваюсь с такой ерундой. Вот код `index.php`

```
<?php header('Location: http://vk.com');
```

Собственно всё его содержание. До заголовков ничего не вывожу. Пробелов нет. Не работает=\ 
 Далее стоят хедеры тоже. В общем, вот весь код:

```
<?php header('Location: http://vk.com');
header('http 200 OK');
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Так он мне прям так и выводит в браузер:

> http 200 OK content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Что за...? Может, кто сталкивался?

Comment: Ощущение, что он как `print()` работает. Только "`location...`" не выводит)

Comment: Конечно я ступлю, но все же... файл закрыт знаками "?>"?

Comment: Закрывающий знак не обязателен, более того даже рекомендуют его не использовать.

Comment: А php сами подключали или готовое решения wamp? У меня с ним была такая проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, проблема в php. 
Другого не дано. Попробуйте переустановить php - скорее всего поможет.

Comment: php у меня был установлен автоматически при установке zend server. Не думаю что ребята из zend могли такую западлянку устроить. попробую. чем черт не шутит. Просто что ж ещё это может быть если не php...

Answer (score 3):

Сохраните файл в UTF-8 без BOM.
Тем самым вы удалите в начале файла спецсимволы, которые вы не видите в редакторе.

Соxранить можно в notepad++

Comment: Не думаю, что причина в этом, т.к. файл с BOM покажет ошибку на строке с Header, о том, что что-то было выведено уже.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php
  header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
  header('Location: http://vk.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

скопировал код, проверил - код рабочий, ошибка где-то в другом месте